# Resizing the grid dynamically using ng-grid (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have two `ng-grids` (grid1 and grid2). When I click `grid1`'s row, I want the second grid to be displayed.

In initial loading I want `grid1`'s width to be set to `100%`. After clicking the row of `grid2`, `grid1` should resize its width.

[Plunker added](http://plnkr.co/edit/PpzGbz5xtx81hVyx4ffc?p=preview)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PpzGbz5xtx81hVyx4ffc?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Resizing ng-grid I've found troublesome in the past. To get the grid to resize, you have to get the entire page to re-layout, which people have written plugins etc for (this is a known problem in ng-grid). However ng-grid is rewritten as ui-grid, and this feature has apparently been fixed - instruction on how to do it in ui-grid [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1774). On top of all ng-grid/ui-grid, consider using [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com), similar interface to ng-grid/ui-grid, but implemented differently - one feature is it resizes automatically without any problems, by setting different width & height attributes to the outer div.